# Batch file that spawns multiple Cmd prompt sessions running different applications

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using a batch file to launch two different applications at the same time in different command line windows. Here is what I have:

```
start cmd /k
cd Windows\System32\ 
diskpart.exe >NUL & 
diskperf.exe >NUL &
```

Repeat for every app you want to run.

I run this and it opens a new command prompt running both applications one after the other. However the other window opens and is waiting for a command.

Any ideas on putting the 2nd and following commands go into the separate command prompts per `&` statement.

Comment: Is powershell an option instead of batch?

Comment: yes. Powershell is an great option. Ideas on how to do this in powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd Windows\System32\ 
cmd /k diskpart.exe
cmd /k diskperf.exe
```

Comment: nope still runs just one cmd prompt window and never launches the second cmd.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Windows XP, so YYMV with more recent versions.

The redirection is hiding execution problems with Diskpart.exe and if it got that far, for diskperf.exe as well. Diskpart is waiting for input, and diskperf requires a command line arguement.

If I understand you correctly, you want near parallel execution of diskpart.exe and diskperf.exe.

This might accomplish what you want - create a batch file with these lines:

```
start cmd.exe /k "diskpart.exe &exit"
start cmd.exe /k "diskperf.exe /? & pause &exit"
start cmd.exe /k "c:\progra~1\intern~1\iexplore.exe &exit"
```

I've removed the redirection, and made the output of each command visible.  The trailing &exit closes the window when the command is finished.  Remove the &pause lines and the programs will exit normally.

I could only get IE to launch if I reduced the path to its 8.3 format.

Answer (score 2):

Tweeked what @TiZon put.

```
start cmd /k diskpart.exe
start cmd /k diskperf.exe
```

Comment: Yeah tried that with: start cmd /k cd windows\system32\ diskpart.exe &
start cmd /k cd windows\system32\ diskperf.exe still get two cmd prompts but says system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: actually that works. Can I do this with CLI apps in program folders? I have set the environmental variable of the Program folder however it crashes when I do this.

Comment: You can just use the full path to call the app. IE `start cmd /k c:\program files\some program\app.exe`

Comment: Put the full path in quotes :)

Comment: Tried both with quotes and without. It opens two cmd prompts but denies knowing the path. Start cmd /k c:\program files\happy app\notsohappyresults.exe Could it be a permission issue?

Comment: What does it actually say? "notsohappyresults.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command"?

Comment: system cannot find the path specified. Copied the path and added it. The kicker is after the error the directory location is c:\users\me\desktop

Comment: I'm out of ideas other than seeing exactly what you're seeing

Comment: Where did you put the quotes Mike? it should look like: start cmd /k "c:\program files\some program\app.exe"

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It may be an issue with the application itself. I did notice that any native app works great. Its 3rd party that will not run.

Answer (score 0):

use

cd Windows\System32\

call diskpart.exe

call diskperf.exe

try

call start cmd /k diskpart.exe
call start cmd /k diskperf.exe

Comment: That works but keeps the commands in one command line window